# How to manange projects that doesn't have gem file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2

Under Rails 2 projects doesn't have the gemfile.

In this case which is the best way to manage the gems?, which gems should I vendor? also I will like to know if there's another way to manage this?

Answer (score 2):

You can manage gem using bundle in rails 2.3 app ,you can refer

http://gembundler.com/rails23.html

http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/03/using-the-new-gem-bundler-today/